# PHP/Postgresql issue populating a dropdownlist with db content

Tags: php, html, postgresql, html-select

I've taken a look at several examples although none seems to work, I intend to populate a drop down box from a table in PostgreSQL db, I've done the reverse which I though it was more complex.
Right now I have the following: (tried different ways already)

```
...
<ul>
  <form name="display" action="" method="post">  
  <label>Select a terminal profile:</label>
  <select name='ddlTerminalProfiles'>
     <option>choose...<option/>
       <?php
        #DB Connection
        $con_string= "host=localhost port=1234 dbname=myDB user=myUser password=myPass";
        $db_con = pg_connect($con_string);              
        #Query for profiles
        $result=pg_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM profiles"); 
        while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
        {
           ?>
           <option value="<? echo $row['profile_name'];?>"><?echo $row['profile_name'];?></option>                                      
<?
}
?>
</select>
<br/>
...
```

Connection is fine, data in database as well.
Also tried triggering with `if(isset($_POST['REFRESH']))...` adding a refresh button. No luck.

Comment: Think about testing the return value for pg_connect() for starters.

Comment: @Carcall Hi, thank you for your input. I do that in the code testing the connection.
<?        #TEST CONNECTION
$stat = pg_connection_status($db_con);
if ($stat === PGSQL_CONNECTION_OK)
{
echo "Connection status : <b style='color:green;'>Successfully</b> connected to <b style='color:green;'>" . pg_dbname($db_con) . "</b> at <b style='color:green;'> " . pg_host($db_con) . " </b></br>";
}
else
{
echo "Connection status : <b style='color:red;'>Unsuccessfull</b>";
}
?>

Comment: @Catcall can you please confirm that the syntax is correct for the option tag?
Thanks!
Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code

```
   <?php
    #DB Connection
    $con_string= "host=localhost port=1234 dbname=myDB user=myUser password=myPass";
    $db_con = pg_connect($con_string);
```

pg_connect() sets the value of $db_con. But this code

```
    #Query for profiles
    $result=pg_query($dbcon, "SELECT * FROM profiles");
```

doesn't use $db_con. It uses $dbcon.

PHP documentation for each function tells you what it returns should there be an error. If a function can return some kind of error status, you need to look for it.

```
$db_con = pg_connect($con_string);
if (!$db_con) {
  echo "pg_connect failed.", PHP_EOL;
}
```

pg_query() and pg_fetch_array() return an error status, too.

String concatenation code is easier to build up piece by piece. Start with

```
echo "<option></option>", PHP_EOL;
```

That should be obviously right; there's no concatenation. Add quotation marks. Failing to escape quotes is a frequent source of errors.

```
echo "<option value=\"\"></option>", PHP_EOL;
```

Add row values using curly brace syntax.

```
echo "<option value=\"{$row['profile_name']}\">{$row['profile_name']}</option>", PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Wait a day or two for more answers, then accept the one that worked best for you. You can do that regardless of reputation.